# How can I query for JSON data type in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, codeigniter

I was looking for a raw query method in CodeIgniter but unable to find specifically for the case I am in, I have JSON data type column in my table and I want to use json query method of MySQL on the column:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE json->'$.user'='najm' AND id='1';
```

when I print my query before passing it to CI db class, it is:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=1 AND `json->'$.user'`='najm' AND id='1'
```

after I print the CI db last_query() I get

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=1 AND `json->'$.user'`='najm' AND id='1'
```

with error:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'json->'$.user'' in 'where clause'

```
    echo $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table . $strWhere;

    $oQuery = $this->db->get_where($this->table,$aData);
    $row = $oQuery->row();
```

Comment: Can you update the table structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is not mysql syntax for Json it is Postgresql check here please.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html